# Javascript wheel event locks to horizontal or vertical movement and does not allow diagonal movement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the wheel event to allow two-finger movement on the PC trackpad. Here's sample code:

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
    console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY)
})
```

My expectation is that deltaX and deltaY will change when I perform a two-finger movement on the trackpad. What I find is that once you start a two-finger horizontal or vertical movement, it locks into that type of movement and forces deltaY to 0 (for horizontal movement) or deltaX to 0 (for vertical movement). If you start with a diagonal movement, then it works as expected and changes deltaX and deltaY properly.

I'm not sure if this is a trackpad-specific problem (I'm on a Surface Book 2) or a Javascript quirk, or if I'm missing something.

You can see this in action here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-touch-trackpad-gesture

1. move two-fingers on touchpad horizontally on box
2. keep fingers on touchpad and then try to go vertically (you cannot, at least on PC/chrome)
3. repeat with vertical and then horizontal
4. start with two-fingers moving diagonally to see the range of motion I'm looking for

Comment: use the `scroll` event instead

Comment: Doesn't work for my scenario. I'm coding a viewport that uses a fixed-sized canvas that does not scroll.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with native scroll handlers? For instance [you can try here](https://jsfiddle.net/e8fxjyhb/). If not, that would probably be an OS limitation. Note that on macOs with a macbook trackpad it works fine on Firefox and Safari. However, Chrome does something very weird here, it defaults the `passive` option of one of the `addEventListener` to `true`  meaning that you won't be able to prevent the default behavior of the events there. You must set this option to false yourself in this browser: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-touch-trackpad-gesture-jqoonc?file=index.js

Comment: You could solve the 2 finger issue by using touch events and scrollBy(xDelta, yDelta)

Comment: Although, Safari has gesture events because it is special. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW23

Comment: Yes, the same thing happens in Chrome/PC for the native scroll handlers. This may be a browser limitation @Kaiido

Comment: Or even an os one. Check you system preference if there is something that can have any incidence on this. (Obviously you won't be able to ask your users to do the same, but it may help narrow the core of the issue). Oh and now that I'm on my phone I realize my Android does this too, on FF.

Comment: Thanks @George - I was planning to implement the gesture events once I got this working. It seems like my API will have to go sans two-finger scrolling :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the by-design behavior in Chrome browsers and they currently have no plans to change it: [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980479).

Chrome locks the direction of the 'wheel' event so that the perpendicular delta is set to 0 once a horizontal or vertical wheel movement starts.

This limits the use of two-finger non-click movements on PC touchpads (e.g., for scrolling across a map with two fingers), but without a change in chromium, I see no path forward.

Answer (score 3):

[w3c spec](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-wheel) says

> A user agent MUST dispatch this event when a mouse wheel has been rotated around any axis, or when an equivalent input device (such as a mouse-ball, certain tablets or touchpads, etc.) has emulated such an action. Depending on the platform and input device, diagonal wheel deltas MAY be delivered either as a single wheel event with multiple non-zero axes or as separate wheel events for each non-zero axis.

Assuming it's implemented correctly by your browser, it would suggest that you may need to handle multiple events rather than a single event.

I would confirm that this is definitely a browser issue, because it sounds more likely that the software/windows is locking a co-ordinate to give you smoother scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This seems to be a Chrome/PC issue. I tested it on Firefox/PC and I don't see the direction-locking issue.

Comment: Might be worth reporting it as a bug `https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list`

Comment: Submitted as https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980479

Comment: Cool, looks good. Might want to link to the w3c spec quote that I put above, and note that it works in other browsers, so people can see that the bug is that the implementation does not match the specification